# How do I update a div with the sum value of 2 form inputs and update when they change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 inputs (one number input and one select) with values that can change, I want to display the sum of both values even when they change on a div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var display = $('#js-cost');
  var base_price = 14;
  var price = 0;

  $('#js-price').on('change', function() {
    base_price = $('#js-price').val();
    display.html(base_price);
  });

  $('#js-duration').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 30) price = 10;
    if ($(this).val() == 45) price = 15;
    if ($(this).val() == 60) price = 30;

    display.html(base_price + price);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="js-duration">
    <option value="15">15 sec</option>
    <option value="30">30 sec (+ $10)</option>
    <option value="45">45 sec (+ $15)</option>
    <option value="60">60 sec (+ $30)</option>
  </select>

  <input id="js-price" type="number" value="14" min="14">
</form>

<p>Current cost: ($<span id="js-cost">14</span> per view)</p>
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: Hi William, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please post your html markup as well?

Comment: We need the rest of your code to help you.

Comment: Ok, I updated my question with the HTML, thanks guys!

Comment: Thanks for adding the relevant code. Please explain exactly what isn't working about the code you entered.  Specifically what you *expect* to happen vs. what *is* happening.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var display = $('#js-cost');
    $('#js-price').on('change', function() {
        display.html(getTotalPrice());
    });

    $('#js-duration').on('change', function() {
        display.html(getTotalPrice());
    });
    function getTotalPrice(){
      var base_price = parseInt($('#js-price').val());
        var duration = parseInt($('#js-duration').val());
        var price = 0;
        15===duration?price=0:30===duration?price=10:45===duration?price=15:60===duration&&(price=20);
      return base_price+price;
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select id="js-duration">
        <option value="15">15 sec</option>
        <option value="30">30 sec (+ $10)</option>
        <option value="45">45 sec (+ $15)</option>
        <option value="60">60 sec (+ $30)</option>
    </select>

    <input id="js-price" type="number" value="14" min="14">
</form>

<p>Current cost: ($<span id="js-cost">14</span> per view)</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. Your `change` event is okay for a select list, but for realtime change of an input that is invariant to whether you are using a keyboard or clicking on arrow keys, use the `.bind('input', callback)` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var display = $('#js-cost');
    var base_price = 14;
    var price = 0;

    $('#js-price').bind('input', function() { 
        base_price = $('#js-price').val();
        display.html(base_price);
    });

    $('#js-duration').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 30) price = 10;
        if ($(this).val() == 45) price = 15;
        if ($(this).val() == 60) price = 30;

        display.html(parseInt(base_price) + parseInt(price));
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select id="js-duration">
        <option value="15">15 sec</option>
        <option value="30">30 sec (+ $10)</option>
        <option value="45">45 sec (+ $15)</option>
        <option value="60">60 sec (+ $30)</option>
    </select>

    <input id="js-price" type="number" value="14" min="14">
</form>

<p>Current cost: ($<span id="js-cost">14</span> per view)</p>
```

Comment: I want the span#js-cost to display the sum of both the select and the input regardless of which one got changed, what happens here is when I change the value of the input it only shows that and ignore the value of the select

Answer (score 0):

If i'm interpreting the question correctly you have almost everything working, you only needed to add the final values together. this initially wasn't working because the `.val` was being returned as a string rather than a number so passing it through a `parseInt` converts it to a number allowing it to work correctly.

Note that `parseInt()` will generally only work on whole numbers, you can use `parseFloat()` to work with decimals

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var display = $('#js-cost');
    var base_price = 14;
    var price = 0;

    $('#js-price').on('change', function() {
        base_price = parseInt($('#js-price').val());
        
        display.html(base_price);
    });

    $('#js-duration').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 30) price = 10;
        if ($(this).val() == 45) price = 15;
        if ($(this).val() == 60) price = 30;

        display.html(base_price+price);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select id="js-duration">
        <option value="15">15 sec</option>
        <option value="30">30 sec (+ $10)</option>
        <option value="45">45 sec (+ $15)</option>
        <option value="60">60 sec (+ $30)</option>
    </select>

    <input id="js-price" type="number" value="14" min="14">
</form>

<p>Current cost: ($<span id="js-cost">14</span> per view)</p>
```

Comment: I may have completely misinterpreted the question but my answer regarding the addition is still valid in relation to the question code so i will leave it anyway.

Comment: the problem I have is, when I select say 60 sec, it goes on to display 44 ($30 + 14) which works but when I increase the value of the input to say 15, it doesn't add instead it overwrites the number and just shows 15 instead of 45